# Question on the proof of doing a nodal trade, almost-toric fibrations

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, integrable-systems

I am trying to understand the details of the proof of lemma $6.3$ of the following notes https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210033.pdf, which give us specific conditions of when we can swap a neighborhood of a focus-focus fiber with a delzant corner.

Specifically I am trying to understand why the condition that the vanishing covector and the collapsing covector generate the whole lattice will prevent an orbifold singularity from occurring.

From my understanding what we are trying to do is to replace a neighborhood of a focus-focus fiber by a Delzant corner. Well in order to do that and not have an orbifold singularity we would need a smoothness condition which would be that the collapsing vectors connecting the edges would generate the whole lattice if I am not mistaken. I am just trying to translate the language of Delzant's theorem into this setting.
However I am not sure how the condition on the collapsing and vanishing covectors give me this.
Furthermore I don't have much "geometric intuition" on this vanishing covector. It's easy to understand that the collapsing covector will be the circle that gets collapsed when we look at the boundary, but I can't seem to understand what this vanishing covector is doing and its relevance.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.